# I want to make a list with all the keys in the dictionary by the list Comprehensions in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

> Here is my dictionary i want to append all the keys in a List by the  list Comprehensions

```
school_copy = {
    'student': {
        '1': {
            'name': 'rihan',
            'roll': '1',
            'class': 'diploma',
        },
        '2': {
            'name': 'sahaib',
            'roll': '2',
            'class': 'diploma'
        }
    },
    'teacher': {
        'head': {
            'name': 'Zahed Ahmed Chowdhury',
            'education': 'msc',
            'institute': 'Asia Pacific'
        },
        'instructor': {
            'name': 'sazedul islam',
            'education': 'bsc',
            'institute': 'duet',
        }
    }
}

lst = []
```

> I do this program by nested for loop. now i want to do this same
> program by list Comprehensions

```
for key in school_copy.keys():
    lst.append(key)
    for key2 in school_copy[key].keys():
        lst.append(key2)
        for key3 in school_copy[key][key2].keys():
            lst.append(key3)
            lst.append(school_copy[key][key2][key3])
print(lst)
```

> As like this output, I want to do this by list Comprehensions

Comment: Why do you absolutely need list comprehension? It's not particularly faster than a traditional `for` loop

Comment: For the learning purpose

Answer (score 3):

This is really a task that lends itself to recursion if you are aiming for greater brevity or readability:

```
def all_kv(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return [x for k, v in obj.items() for x in [k, *all_kv(v)]]
    return [obj]
    
lst = all_kv(school_copy)
```

Note also that this will work for any (even mixed) nesting depth.
Even more elegant, pythonic, and space efficient will be a recursive generator:

```
def all_kv(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k, v in obj.items():
            yield k
            yield from all_kv(v)
    else:
        yield obj

lst = list(all_kv(school_copy))
```

Comment: Its really awesome thank you so much...  Would you like to suggest me a source to learn more about it?

Comment: The documentation is usually a good starting point, e.g. on [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators).